# Computer drawing surfaces

Tags: drawing

I was looking at some Adobe products and noticed [at this page](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html?promoid=DTELX) the artist appears to be drawing on her computer screen directly, it appears to be a Mac.  How is the artist doing this?  Is she using a special type of screen hooked to a computer or is this a stand-alone computer?  Is there any reference material available about devices like this?

Comment: By the way, in case you don't have a graphics tablet and are looking for something cheap to get started, the same company that makes that screen also makes surfaces without a screen, but which are much better than a mouse (for example, they have pressure sensitivity). The Wacom Bamboo Splash can be aquired from as low as $60 on the US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [Wacom Cintiq 21UX](http://www.wacom.com/en/Products/Cintiq/Cintiq21UX.aspx), Wacom's 21" pen display. On a 1-10 scale it rates about an 11 if you're a digital artist.